# JAX-RS Handle variable number of FormParam

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

In Java, I am implementing a server where client can pass some data (Key-value pairs) using post query. I have decided to make a REST Service and I am planning to use JAX-RS along with Jetty.

I have no previous knowledge about the keys to be send here. Is there any way to browse over all the KV pairs POSTed by client? I know that if key is known we could retrieve data as in -

```
@Path("/testpath")
public class test {

    @POST
    @Path("/level1")
    public Response getData(
        @FormParam("key1") String val1,
        @FormParam("key2") int val2) {

        return Response.status(200)
            .entity("getData is called, Key1 : " + val1 + ", Key2 : " + val2)
            .build();

    }

}
```

In the above example, I could have **N** of different keys!

I am planning to use vanilla JAX-RS without Jersey, or RESTeasy. However I am open to the options when not possible in JAX-RS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MultiValuedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) :

```
@Path("/testpath")
public class test {
    @POST
    @Path("/level1")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response getData(MultiValuedMap<String, String> params) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("getData is called, ");
        for(String param : params.keySet()) {
            sb.append(param + " : " + params.getFirst(param) + ", ");
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(sb.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying exactly the same example, what can be the reason it doesn't work?